# values are populated in iOS 8 but null in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8

the following code works perfectly in iOS 8 but not iOS 7.1. I'm using this code to populate textfields and button text. The values are all null in iOS 7

```
-(void) onSuccess: (AppUpdate*) response{
if (response.forceUpdate == true) {
    AppCheckForUpdateViewController *checkForUpdateViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Check_For_Update_View"];
    [self presentViewController:checkForUpdateViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    checkForUpdateViewController.messageTitle = response.message;
    checkForUpdateViewController.appURL = response.updateUrl;
    checkForUpdateViewController.upgradeMessage = response.title;
    checkForUpdateViewController.cancelBtnMessage = response.cancelButtonText;
    checkForUpdateViewController.upgradeBtnMessage = response.updateButtonText;
}
```

}

Comment: There's not enough information here to go on.  Maybe try some more troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by setting the properties before I present the viewcontroller

```
-(void) onSuccess: (AppUpdate*) response{
    if (response.forceUpdate == true) {
        AppCheckForUpdateViewController *checkForUpdateViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Check_For_Update_View"];
        checkForUpdateViewController.messageTitle = response.message;
        checkForUpdateViewController.appURL = response.updateUrl;
        checkForUpdateViewController.upgradeMessage = response.title;
        checkForUpdateViewController.cancelBtnMessage = response.cancelButtonText;
        checkForUpdateViewController.upgradeBtnMessage = response.updateButtonText;
        [self presentViewController:checkForUpdateViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```